# Babel failes to compile plugin it should be ignoring

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Trying to compile my code with the webpack loader which i have set to ignore node_modules and have not been able to bypass the error below. I've tried clearing out my node_modules and reinstalling as well as adding and removing packages but have been unable to clear the block:

```
    /home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-plugin-     transform-react-jsx/lib/index.js:16
    var visitor = require("babel-helper-builder-react-jsx")({ /*istanbul ignore next*/
                                                         ^

    TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at exports.default (index.js:14:17)
    at Function.memoisePluginContainer (/home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:134:13)
    at Function.normalisePlugin (/home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:168:32)
    at /home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:208:30
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (/home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:180:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:300:36)
    at /home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:371:14
    at /home/mgarf/Documents/testApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:392:24
    at Array.map (native)
```

Here is my webpackconfig snippet.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
require('style-loader');
require('css-loader');
require('babel-register')({
   ignore: /\.css$/,
});

...

module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            plugins: [
              ['react-transform', {
                transforms: [
                  {
                    transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
                    imports: ['react'],
                    locals: ['module']
                  }, {
                    transform: 'react-transform-catch-errors',
                    imports: ['react', 'redbox-react']
                  }
                ]
              }]
            ]
          }
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
      ]
    }
```

and package.json:

```
      "dependencies": {
        "async": "^1.5.2",
        "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
        "bookshelf": "^0.10.0",
        "compression": "^1.6.2",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
        "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
        "express": "^4.13.4",
        "express-validator": "^2.20.4",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
        "knex": "^0.11.7",
        "moment": "^2.12.0",
        "morgan": "^1.7.0",
        "mysql": "^2.10.2",
        "nodemailer": "^2.3.0",
        "nunjucks": "^2.4.1",
        "react": "^15.2.1",
        "react-cookie": "^0.4.5",
        "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
        "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
        "react-router": "^2.4.0",
        "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
        "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
        "redbox-react": "^1.2.4",
        "redux": "^3.3.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
        "request": "^2.69.0",
        "webpack": "^1.12.14",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^0.11.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
        "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0-beta1",
        "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0-rc-3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.8.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.8.0",
        "chai": "^3.5.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "enzyme": "^2.3.0",
        "fetch-mock": "3.0.2",
        "mocha": "^2.4.5",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.0.2",
        "react-date-picker": "^5.3.21",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
        "sinon": "^1.17.3",
        "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "supertest": "^1.2.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "6.1.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you including your Babel presets somehow?

Comment: Yep through babel.rc. It's just React and ES2015

Comment: The Babel loader doesn't automatically know about babelrc. You have to parse that file and then put it within the loader '''query''' property. Or, to test quickly, just add the presets in directly. See Usage at https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/blob/master/README.md